# Intermediate value theorem and extreme value theorem - on non-closed intervals

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose f is a continuous function on [a, infinity) and lim f(x) = y [this is the limit as x goes to infinity] and f(a) < y. Prove that

1) for any f(a) < b < y there is x0 ∈ [a, ∞) such that f(x0) = b.
2) f attains its minimum on [a, infinity)

I have partial proofs - i need help completing/ understanding them

For part 1): Choose M>y. Then there is c in [a, infinity) such that f(x)>M for any x>c (however I do not understand why this holds). After this it says to use intermediate value theorem to prove the result which also I don't know how to apply

For part 2): There exists M>0 such that f(x) > f(a) for any x>=M (which theorem or property does this follow from?). Then by extreme value theorem, on [a,M], f attains its minimum y0 at some point c in [a,M]. Then y0 is also the minimum of f on [a, infinity) (Why is this true??)

Answer (score 0):

1) Is *false* as the function $-\dfrac{1}{x}$ shows on $[1, \infty)$ (here $a=1$ and $y = 0$).

2) Consider an interval $[a, b]$ such that for $x > b$ we have $f(x) > y - \varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon$ is $\dfrac{y-f(a)}{2}.$ On $[a, b]$ $f$ attains a minimum which is easily seen to be global. Q.E.D.

Comment: I doubt statement 1) is false. The questions asks to prove that there is an x0 such that f(x0) = y. And this must be done using intermediate value theorem (says in the hint)

Comment: For the proof to 2) - we only know that lim f(x) = y ....how do we get f(x) > y- epsilon

Comment: I have edited the question - there was a typo in part 1

Answer (score 0):

I don´t get your attempts.

Here is one way though.

1) Take $\epsilon=\frac{y - b}{2}$. Since $y=\lim f(x)$ at infinity, there is some $A > a$ such that $x>A$ implies $|f(x)-y|<\epsilon$, i.e., $b<\frac{y + b}{2}=y-\epsilon < f(x) < y + \epsilon$. Apply the intermediate value theorem on $[a, x]$.

2) By the previous item, there is some $t$ such that $f(t)=\frac{y + f(a)}{2}$. For $x$ sufficiently large, we have $\frac{y + f(a)}{2} < f(x)$. Since $f$ is continuous and $[a, t]$ compact, $f$ attains a minimum on $[a, t]$.

Comment: How do we know that "...there is some A>a and some x>A such that b<f(x)<y" Is this some property or theorem we are using here? My attempts were the hints given for the question and we are supposed to complete the proof by giving reasons as to why each statement in the hint holds

Comment: Thank you! I understand part 1 at least. But can you tell me why the statement in the hint hold? i.e. "There exists M>0 such that f(x) > f(a) for any x>=M" Which theorem or property is this

Comment: As $x$ approaches infinity, $f(x)$ becomes close to $y$ and sooner or later, it gets through the midpoint of $[f(a), y]$ and never looks back.

Comment: What about this statment - "Then there is c in [a, infinity) such that f(x)>M for any x>c" - why does this hold?

Comment: also - for part 2 - you say that - "f attains a minimum on [a,t]" but how does this translate to f attaining minimum on [a,infinity)